# Ubuntu does not reconize HDMI port

Tags: 18.04, graphics, hdmi

I have a laptop with two graphics cards:

- Intel
- Nvidia

I have the official Nvidia driver and use the Nvidia card. However, when I plug a display via HDMI, it is not reconize either by the Ubuntu display app or by xrandr:

```
 nakrule@mordor ~ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    60.00    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   ...
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is the output for the command `lshw`

```
 nakrule@mordor ~ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ac000000-acffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ad000000-ad07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:154 memory:ab000000-abffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I tried using my Intel card as well, but this does not work except when if I remove the Nvidia driver with `sudo apt purge nvidia-kernel-common-390`. Then, all my video ports are detected. However, as the Intel GPU is used, performance are way worse. How could I still have the Nvidia card used and access video port ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the line `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` to `options nvidia-drm modeset=0` solved my issue. To find in which file this setting is present, run the following command:

- `grep modeset /etc/modprobe.d/*`
- `grep modeset /lib/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: This solves the issue when the NVIDIA Card is selected but, not when the Intel is selected.